# Rails I18n-js: missing translation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I'm using [I18n-js gem](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) for localiztion of js files. I've installed it with help of gem Readme and it worked for the first time.

The problem is when I add new translations to my `translations.js` file with rake task `rake i18n:js:export` translations not showing in my templates - only `missing translation` (development and production has same situation), although `translations.js` contents all the new translations.

application.js

```
//= require i18n
//= require i18n/translations
```

What did I miss? If you need more information please comment about it. Thanks

Comment: Same here, did you solved your problem gracefully ? :)

Answer (score 13):

Run `rake tmp:clear`

I faced the same issue and this command solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I haven't found better solution:

Add `= javascript_include_tag 'translations'` to the view file

remove `//= require i18n/translations` from `application.js`